# Moving value from below row to upper one

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can move value of a column to upper row where banakaccount is null

Below is my table data of two creditor  TABLE1

```
UniqueDatabaseNo    Creditor    BankAccountNo
882370              300020         NULL
NULL                300020         NULL
NULL                300020           NULL
0                   300020     NL21SOGE0946
NULL                300020      NULL
NULL                380910      NULL
0                   380910        1432981
0                   380910       NL98RABO0181
NULL                380910       NULL
2293483             380910        NULL
```

I NEED BELOW OUT PUT WHERE UniqueDatabaseNo > 0 AND ON SAME ROW BANK ACCOUNT SHOULD ON SAME ROW

Here is desired output

```
UniqueDatabaseNo    Creditor    BankAccountNo
882370               300020     NL21SOGE0946
2293483              380910     NL98RABO0181
```

I tried below query but it is not working correctly

```
select * from TABLE1
where  uniquedatabaseno >0
union all
select * from TABLE1
where BankAccountNo  LIKE '[a-Z][a-Z]%'
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using aggregation:

```
select max(UniqueDatabaseNo) as UniqueDatabaseNo, Creditor,
       max(case when BankAccountNo like '[a-Z][a-Z]%' then BankAccountNo end) as BankAccountNo
from t
group by Creditor;
```

Edit:

You might was conditional logic for `UniqueDatabaseNo` as well:

```
select max(case when UniqueDatabaseNo > 0 then UniqueDatabaseNo end) as UniqueDatabaseNo
```

This is not necessary for your sample data.

Comment: This will only work in case each creditor does have a bankaccount and uniquedata that fits the condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select UniqueDatabaseNo,Creditor,TT.BankAccountNo
from TABLE1 T1
OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT BankAccountNo as 'BankAccountNo'
  FROM TABLE1 T2
  WHERE T1.Creditor=T2.Creditor AND T2.BankAccountNo IS NOT NULL
)TT
where  T1.uniquedatabaseno >0 AND T1.UniqueDatabaseNo IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out NULL values:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE
    UniqueDatabaseNo > 0
AND BankAccountNo IS NOT NULL
```